# Can I get the color picker from Monet Engine in the browser?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm wondering if it seems possible at the moment to get the color palette of an android device in a browser. I found only a module for react native, which does not quite suit me.

The module for react native is not quite suitable for me, since my application is embedded on the device according to the manifest file.